# How can I properly set up my Spring persistance models so that specific models correctly subclass a "generic" model?

Tags: java, spring, persistence

I would like to have different kinds of "alerts" in my application, so I thought I would create an abstract class for general Alerts and have my specific alerts extend that.

```
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class Alert<A extends Serializable> {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @CreatedDate
    @Temporal(TIMESTAMP)
    protected OffsetDateTime dateCreated;

    @LastModifiedDate
    @Temporal(TIMESTAMP)
    protected OffsetDateTime dateModified;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

}
```

Now, for example, one of my specific alerts:

```
@Entity
public class SpecificAlertAlpha extends Alert<Serializable> implements Serializable{
    private String description;
    private int someNumber;
    private boolean someYesNo;
}
```

In my database, I do not want a generic "Alerts" table, instead I want tables for each of the subclass alerts.

I have seen several examples through my searches, but nothing that seems to reach out and grab me as far as what I need. In [one example](https://gist.github.com/banterCZ/6164973), the subclass that extends the superclass has `Long` as the type in angle brackets, but I am not sure what that is for. I thought maybe the ID, but I am now lost in confusion.

How can I set up my models so that they can do what I would like them to do?

Comment: What's the type parameter `A` used for? The above configuration won't use a single generic table. The `@MappedSuperClass` won't create a table at all, and `SpecificAlertAlpha` will get its own table, as it's an `@Entity`. It's a common idiom to have entities extend a class that defines the primary key and a created/updated and other default columns.

Comment: In the example I linked to, they used PK, but I used A because it is an alert. Probably completely wrong, though.